# How to detect IP changer

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, ip

Our website prevents users from registering more than once from the same IP address. Someone created a bot to automatically register every 5 seconds using an IP changer. Is it possible to detect an IP changer? Or is there any other info we could fetch from a browser to identify the user?

Comment: Checking the IP is not at all secure to prevent bot, you should implement more bot-specific solutions, like for example a captcha.

Comment: Captcha is also there.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the brute-force of register page using,

1. Using the captcha such as recaptcha, preferred one
2. Validate using the OTP/token on mobile or email at the time of registration process, depends on your application context